# How to does Linux manage VM allocation per process? OOM crash

Tags: linux, out-of-memory, virtual-machine, vps, virtual-memory

I'm currently prototyping a very light weight TCP server based on a custom protocol. It's written in C++ and using Boost Asio for cross-platform sockets. When I monitor the process on Windows it only eats about <3MB in memory, barely grows with many concurrent connections (I tested up to 8).

I built the same server for Linux and put it on a 128MB + 64MB swap VPS for testing. It runs fine and my testings are successful, but the process gets killed in the middle of the night by kernel. I checked the logs and it was out of memory (OOM score was 0).

I highly doubt my process has memory leaks. I checked my server logs and only 1 person has connected to it the previous night, which should not result in OOM. The process sleeps for majority of the time as it only does processing if Boost's async handler wakes up the main thread to process the packet.

What I did notice is that the default VM allocation for the process is a whooping 89MB (using top command). And as soon as I make a connection it is doubled to about 151MB. My VPS has about 100MB free ram and all 64MB swap while running the server, so the the only thing I could think of is that the process tried to allocate more virtual memory going over the ~164MB remaining and went beyond the physical limit and triggered the OOM-Killer.

I've since used the ulimit command to limit the VM allocation to 30MB and it seems to be working fine, but I'll have to wait a while to see if it actually helps the issue.

My question is how does Linux determine how much VM to allocate for a process? Is there a compiler/linker setting I can use to reduce the default VM reservation? Is my reasoning correct or are there other reasons for the OOM?

Comment: What do you mean by `VM allocation to 30MB ...` ? Address space, or attached pages?

Comment: I use the command "ulimit -v 30720" before running the process

Comment: That is the maximum address space. You probably need `-d     The maximum size of a process's data segment` . Please see `man 1 bash` or `man 2 setrlimit` ... Or try `-m     The maximum resident set size (many systems do not  honor this limit)`

Comment: And a hint: until you really understand demand paging and VM, you should **only** look at the `RES` (or `RSS`) collumn in top.

Comment: yeah so my hypothesis is that it's the VM allocation going over physical limit causing OOM, not the actual usage, res is only about 1.2MB for my server. why do you think that it has anything to do with data segment? Data segment does not change at runtime afaik

Comment: Data segment contains initialised+uninitialised data+heap. You should start by only restricting the wired (resident) memory ( -m flag) and watch a bit. Maybe later you could restrict the address space, too,

Comment: according https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment data segment does not contain heap